# Store output of command in variable where the command is already executed/stored in it's own variable - bash script

Tags: linux, bash, shell, syntax

I have a command that is stored in a variable. I would like to execute that command and then store the response of that command in a variable. I'm having an issue with syntax errors for the responseVar=$("{commandVar}") line as it seems to trigger a "no such file or directory" error instead of actually running the command/storing the output in the response variable.

```
commandVar="curl --location -g --request POST 'https://172.217.25.35/rest-gateway/rest/api/v1/auth/token' --header 'Content-Type: application/json' --header 'Authorization: Basic U0FNcWE6NTYyMFNhbSE=' --data-raw '{"grant_type": "client_credentials"}'"

responseVar=$("{commandVar}")

echo "Response of command: ${responseVar}"
```

Does anyone know the correct syntax on how I would do this? I need to eventually parse the output of the command which is why I need to store the response in it's own variable.

Comment: Don't store commands in variables; variables are for data, not executable code. If you really need to store a command, use a function or possibly an array. See [BashFAQ #50: "I'm trying to put a command in a variable, but the complex cases always fail!"](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/050) and ]"Why does shell ignore quoting characters in arguments passed to it through variables?"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12136948/why-does-shell-ignore-quoting-characters-in-arguments-passed-to-it-through-varia) (but ignore all suggestions involving `eval` -- it is a massive bug magnet).

Comment: Um, why you need this intermediate var? Why not just `responseVar=$( curl ... )`

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to execute a program named `{commandVar}`, and this program does not exist in your PATH.

To start with, you better use an array to store your command, each array element holding one command argument:

```
commandVar=(curl --location -g --request POST 'https://172.217.25.35/rest-gateway/rest/api/v1/auth/token' --header 'Content-Type: application/json' --header 'Authorization: Basic U0FNcWE6NTYyMFNhbSE=' --data-raw '{"grant_type": "client_credentials"}')
```

With this, you can execute it by

```
"${commandVar[@]}"
```

respectively store its standardoutput into a variable like this:

```
responseVar=$( "${commandVar[@]}" )
```